# Laravel hasManyThrough polymorphic table not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I've following relationship:

```
class Project extends Model
{
   public function invitors()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(Invitation::class)
   }
}

// User model
class User extends Model
{
    public function invitations()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Invitation', 'invitee');
    }
}

// Business Model
class Business extends Model
{
    public function invitations()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Invitation', 'invitee');
    }
}

// Invitation model
class Invitation extends Model
{
    public function invitee()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function project()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

What I want is to get project invitors (users, and businesses). When I use from `$project->invitors->invitee` its not working.

Comment: ```$project->find(1)->invitors``` should works fine

Comment: I've project details, it's already bound to the route.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `$project->invitors` is a collection of `Invitation` instances, and it hasn't property `invitee`. You can use helper `pluck` to loop `$project->invitors` and get their invitees:

```
$invitees = $project->invitors->pluck('invitee');
```

As a response to the first comment:
to get specific attributes of fetched linked models ("invitee") you can specify accessors:

```
class Business extends Model
{
    ...

    public function getInviteeNameAttribute() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    ...

    public function getInviteeNameAttribute() {
        return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
    }
}
```

...then get that attribute from `invitee`:

```
$invitees[0]->invitee_name
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: How we can add select clause to the pluck, I should select specific columns from invitees `business`, and `user`, and alias those columns, suppose from business I should get its name, but from user I should get concat of first_name and last_name as name